# ffmper with vlc - too heavy screen grabbing, resulting injumpy file, frame loss

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, screen-grab

I'm using 'vlc/ffmpeg' package to grab the screen and convert it to H.264 file.

The problem arises when the host is heavily loaded. I need to maintain correct time stamps and use the 5 fps (relatively low frame rate). Yet sometimes the resulting file jumps few seconds forward, apparently due to frame loss. 
I can deal with the frame loss, it's OK, but I need to duplicate lost frames to maintain correct timing.

My configuration file:

**vlc.exe  screen:// -I dummy --verbose=2  --one-instance :screen-fps=5  :screen-caching=10000 :sout=#transcode{venc=x264{preset=ultrafast,tune=zerolatency},vcodec=h264,fps=5,vb=3000,width=1024,height=576,acodec=none}:file{dst="C:\tmp\output.mp4"}**

What should I add/config to preserve proper time stamps and clip duration?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found adding 'copyts' option does exactly what I need.